# SLO request returning HTML page instead of redirecting to keycloak single logout

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, pac4j, single-logout

I have sso configured for my application with keycloak and I wish to do single logout.
When I call my endpoint for single logout `/slo`, I got this from the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <noscript>
            <p>
                <strong>Note:</strong>
                Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
                you must press the Continue button once to proceed.
            
            </p>
        </noscript>
        <form action="http&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;localhost&#x3a;8080&#x2f;realms&#x2f;master&#x2f;protocol&#x2f;saml" method="post">
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="https&#x25;3A&#x25;2F&#x25;2Fhostname&#x25;2Flogout"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="some_value"/>
            </div>
            <noscript>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
                </div>
            </noscript>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me so that my application will properly redirect this request to keycloak?
I am using SAML Pac4j for my application.

I have tried manually setting Logout Service POST Binding URL in keycloak UI to what I got from sp_metadata and also added Valid post logout redirect URIs to my application URI. I have added relay state to logout endpoint of my application `/logout`